# Harmonic functions in upper half plane

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $\mathbb H^+$ denote the upper half plane in $\mathbb R^2$. Consider the following equation
\begin{equation}\label{pf0}
\begin{aligned}
\begin{cases}
\Delta u=0\,\quad &\text{on $\mathbb H^+$},
\\
u=f\,\quad &\text{on $\partial \mathbb H^+$,}\\
\end{cases}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $f \in L^2(\mathbb R)$. My question is what is the right Sobolev space where the classical solution to this equation belongs to.

Comment: If $H^+=\{(x,t): t>0\}$ then $\|u(\cdot,t)\|_2 \le \|f\|_2$ for every  $t>0$ but $u$ does not belong to $L^2(H^+)$ and the same holds for $p \neq 2$. Usually one looks at the solution using $t$ as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, the problem is ill-posed if you consider classical Sobolev spaces. Indeed, even the trace operator $H^{s} \to H^{s-1/2}$ is ill-defined for $s = 1/2$. There are anisotropic Sobolev spaces that have been defined that would do the job (See https://homepage.univie.ac.at/piotr.chrusciel/papers/Dissertationes/Dissertationes.pdf) but I have to think more about this..